# i can cache even 5Mb of data in client side using normal javascript cache. then why should i go for html5 localstorage

Tags: html

i am using browser cache to store approximately 5MB of data. if it is possible to store this data using browser cache why should i go for localStorage of html5.
Will the browser speed get affected due to the data size ?

Comment: It may depend on how you store your 5MB of data. As static files? Cookies? Some other way?

Answer (score 0):

I see you are concerned by the speed. Unlike cookies, sessionStorage and localStorage are never sent back and forth between browsers (client) and servers so it doesn't slow the data traffic between your browser and the server.

Moreover, localStorage and sessionStorage have a nice JavaScript API to manage the data (not like cookies).

Does this answer your question?